# error: no match for ‘operator>>’ for my class

Tags: c++, error-handling, operator-overloading, fstream, iostream

I have an error that says:

```
error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}’ and ‘const int*’)
    inputStream >> getZipcode();
```

When I have included `#include <iostream>` and `#include <fstream>` and I'm not using an operator overload function so I don't understand the problem. I also have a note that says this:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/iostream:40:0,
                 from Strings.h:5,
                 from Sensor.h:5,
                 from Car.h:4,
                 from Agency.h:4,
                 from Agency.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:168:7: note: candidate: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(bool&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type = std::basic_istream<char>] <near match>
       operator>>(bool& __n)
       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/istream:168:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
Agency.cpp:79:29: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘bool&’ to an rvalue of type ‘bool’
    inputStream >> getZipcode();
```

What this function is supposed to data for a Rental Car's Agency that includes the name of the Agency and the zipcode. And then read in the "inventory" or the data of cars the Agency has, such as: make, model, owner, year, sensor, and baseprice.

Here is my Agency header file and my implementation for getZipcode() on a seperate source file:

```
class Agency {
    private:
        char m_name[256];
        int m_zipcode[5];
        Car m_inventory[5];
    public:
        Agency();
        //~Agency();
        const char *getName();
        const int *getZipcode();
        void setName(const char *name);
        void setZipcode(const int *zipcode);
        const Agency &operator[](const int index);
        void readData();
        void printData();
        void printAvailableCars();
};

const int *Agency::getZipcode() {
    return m_zipcode;
}
```

```
    void Agency::readData() {
            ifstream inputStream;
            char inputfile[50];
            const int *tempZip = getZipcode();
            Car *tempInvt = m_inventory;
            char tempMake[256], tempModel[256], tempOwner[256], tempType[256];
            int tempYear;
            float tempBaseprice;
            bool tempAvailable;
            Sensor tempSensor[3];
            Sensor *sensorPtr = tempSensor;

            cout << "Enter file name: ";
            cin >> inputfile;

            inputStream.open(inputfile);
            if (inputStream.is_open()) {
                inputStream >> m_name;
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    inputStream >> getZipcode();
                    tempZip++;
                }
                    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                        inputStream >> tempYear;
                        inputStream >> tempMake;
                        inputStream >> tempModel;
                        inputStream >> tempBaseprice;
                        tempInvt->setYear(tempYear);
                        tempInvt->setMake(tempMake);
                        tempInvt->setModel(tempModel);
                        tempInvt->setBaseprice(tempBaseprice);
                        inputStream.get();
                        while (inputStream.peek() != '}') {
                            inputStream >> tempType;
                            sensorPtr->setType(tempType);
                            if (myStringCompare(tempType, "gps") == 0) {
                                sensorPtr->setExtracost(5.0);
                                sensorPtr->getGps_cnt() + 1;
                            }
                            else if (myStringCompare(tempType, "camera") == 0) {
                                sensorPtr->setExtracost(10.0);
                                sensorPtr->getCamera_cnt() + 1;
                            }
                            else if (myStringCompare(tempType, "lidar") == 0) {
                                sensorPtr->setExtracost(15.0);
                                sensorPtr->getLidar_cnt() + 1;
                            }
                            else if (myStringCompare(tempType, "radar") == 0) {
                                sensorPtr->setExtracost(20.0);
                                sensorPtr->getRadar_cnt() + 1;
                            }
                            else {
                                sensorPtr->setExtracost(0.0);
                            }
                            sensorPtr++;
                        }
                        inputStream.get();
                        tempInvt->updatePrice();
                        inputStream >> tempAvailable;
                        inputStream >> tempOwner;
                        tempInvt->setAvailable(tempAvailable);
                        tempInvt->setOwner(tempOwner);
                    }
                    tempInvt++;
            }
        }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2XNv.png
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the full error message

Comment: You can't read pointers from an istream. What is `inputStream >> getZipcode();` supposed to do?

Comment: @idclev463035818 I added more information

Comment: why are you not using `std::string` for strings?

Comment: @idclev463035818 I just want to get a better understanding of using char pointers as well as int pointers

Comment: part of that is to understand that you dont need pointers for strings or arrays, because you can use `std::string` and `std::vector` / `std::array`. Raw pointers are rare in modern C++. Writing a swap function eg would be a valid use case for pointers, but even for that you would rather use references or even better use what is already existing (`std::swap`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error comes from trying to use istream with a pointer, there is another error with the design, it is not recommended to use a get to change the internal data of the class, so you better program a set function. I have assumed that you are trying to read a ZipCode number by number and its a 4 digit number. But if you are not trying to do that, give me more information and code.

```
int aux_Zip[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    inputStream >> aux_Zip[i];
}
setZipCode(aux_Zip);
```

Comment: you dont need a loop to read a 4 digit number. Actually if the file does contain a 4 digit number then `inputStream >> aux_Zip[0];` will already read all the 4 digits

Comment: btw I also cannot agree to "it is not recommended to use a get to change the internal data of the class" in this generality. Of course getters are to get something not to set, but sometimes getters do eg some bookkeeping and then they do modify internal members and I do not see what would be bad about that

Comment: or consider a lazy-evaluated private member of the class, the corresponding getter would first retreive the value if necessary, store it internally and only then return it

Comment: Ok, first the loop, it all depends on the format of the input, I assumed that the format is like 4 4 4 4, so as I said, there is few information. Related with the matter of the get, all my teachers have said that we have to ensure the encapsulation of the data members of the class.

Comment: If the question is unclear then better ask for clarification instead of answering based on speculations. Second, my counter arguments are not in contrast to encapsulation. To the contrary, if you modify a privately encapsulated member in a getter, this **is** encapsulation.

Comment: look at this example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/U0HjDZvyqqqlDO6U `counter` is encapsulated, the user of the class will never see it.

Comment: Hello! I added more code and info to my question. Sorry for not making it clear

Comment: @KamiJuanmi Hello! So I was wondering why is there an error from using istream with a pointer?

Comment: @PhilippPenalber Hi! Pointers keep the memory adress of some data, for example a pointer to an integer that is located at the cell 1574, the pointer have the memory adress 1574 but doesn't know if there is a 4 or a 5 in that adress, to access to that data you use the operator *. And it's logical that you don't introduce by istream a memory adress, so c++ doesn't have defined the i/ostream for them because it makes no sense. Hope that this help you :)

Answer (score -1):

`getZipcode()` is a call to a function that returns a `const int*`. It doens't make any sense to read an integer (zip code) from your inputStream and try to store this in a function call.

This would work if you want to read the zip code from file:

```
int *tempZip = getZipcode();
if (inputStream.is_open()) {
    inputStream >> m_name;
    inputStream >> tempZip; 
}
```

If you want to extract the zip code from your input stream `int *tempZip` mustn't be `const`.

As commented, the better solution would be to read to `int` directly without using `int*`.

```
int tempZip = getZipcode(); // not sure what getZipcode() should do
if (inputStream.is_open()) {
    inputStream >> m_name;
    inputStream >> tempZip; 
}
```

Comment: in what context does it make sense to read a `int*` from a stream (assuming it would work) ?

Comment: That is the given data type in the original post (and yes, it works). The error is not coming from the pointer, but the fact that he tries to extract to a `const int*`. That's not overwritten, such as trying to extract to a `const int` wouldn't work.

Comment: it is hard to imagine that reading a `int*` from the file is what OP really wants.

Comment: Hello! I just added more info to my question. Sorry for not making it clear.

Comment: Why do you need `const int*` in your getter and setter function for the zip code? Just `int`would be sufficient.
And why do you used this `inputStream >> getZipcode();` for reading in the zip code?

Comment: @geoidiot I used `const int *` because I thought that since a zipcode is an array of intergers I can just retrieve the data through the use of pointers.